# What options are there to restrict returned data to a dynamic Google Form from script run as me?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, google-forms

Been trying to create a vacation request form using Google Forms that links to a spreadsheet of vacation entitlement/usage for all employees. That spreadsheet data needs to be restricted to only me.

The Google Form would show the user only their vacation entitlement and usage info and then populate the responses in another sheet which will later generate the Supervisor approval form..and so on...

I've researched a bit of oauth2 and Web App authorization but have spent a month reading up and need a pointer. I need to be sure that the user only gets access to their entitlement data in the form.

All users would be within our domain. Is there a method specifically for this?

What is the best way to create this type of app in Google Apps Script/Cloud Platform?

Comment: You can't dynamically change the content of a live Google Form, so your only option would be to dynamically create one and send your user to that. Obviously whatever script you use to create said Form can apply arbitrary logic when populating its questions.

Comment: Thank you. So a script running as myself could create the form, point results to a spreadsheet and then that sheet have a script to compile my results into a master sheet or tab. That only leaves being sure I'm serving that employee data to only that employee.